# Distinguish between Oracle mod_plsql and ORDS in frontend

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords, mod-plsql

I would need to distinguish in my frontend what kind of Oracle backend (mod_plsql or ords) is running and cannot seem to find a reliable way to do so. Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design to not "leak" what the backend details. A custom mechanism would be required to know this in the front end.

ORDS does inject an http header into  OWA CGI ENVs for this purpose. A procedure like this could allow someone to write a a proc to return a 1/0 or something to know if ords or not ords.

```
create or replace procedure whoami as
begin
if  owa_util.get_cgi_env( 'APEX_LISTENER_VERSION' ) is not null   then

    htp.prn('ords');
else
    htp.prn('not ords');
end if;
end;
/
```